# How to convert a TCP inputstream into a UPD datgram byte array?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, io

I have some string to convert to stream which I use

```
outputStream.write(string.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

and send through TCP socket, and then the server convert these stream to byte array and send to UDP socket. The problem is because the origional string size varies, and I don't want to define the byte array size. What's most optimized way to do the later one.

Comment: I would set the size and the bytes in the same packet.

Answer (score 0):

When sending the byte array on to the UDP socket, let the first byte be the length of the string you send. The drawback is that you can then only send 0 to 255 bytes. I don't know about Java, but you could get the lowest 8 bits of the length and send as the first byte, and the high 8 bits as the second byte, then you can send 0 to 65535 bytes.

The other program that reads from the UDP socket of course have to read the first one or two bytes, and construct an integer from that. Then it knows the length and can read the exact number of bytes.

Comment: UDP packets are self-contained, there is no need for an embedded length value.  The packet size *is* the string length.  I would, however, send the string length over the TCP connection instead, so the receiver knows how many bytes to then send over UDP.